# Sourcing a sh file is illegal in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

After solving [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523606/fsl-sh-cannot-be-sourced/523610?noredirect=1#comment712801_523610) one, I tried to source the sh script editing `csh.cshrc`. I added the following lines in its end:

```sh
. /etc/fsl/5.0/fsl.sh
setenv FREESURFER_HOME/home/User/freesurfer
source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.csh
```

But I get the error `/usr/sbin/.: Permission denied.`. I tried to change it to `source /etc/fsl/5.0/fsl.sh` bt then I got the error `Illegal variable name.`.

The file I'm trying to source is:

```sh
# FSL configuration file
#  - to be sourced by the user, typically in .bashrc or equivalent
#  - note that the user should set
# Written by Mark Jenkinson, FMRIB Analysis Group, University of Oxford
# Modified for Debian by Michael Hanke <michael.hanke@gmail.com>

# clean out previous fsl PATH components: DO NOT EDIT THE NEXT TWO LINES
PATH=$( echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep  -v "/usr/lib/fsl/" | tr -s "\n" ":" | sed  's/:$//') 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$( echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep  -v "/usr/lib/fsl/" |  tr -s "\n" ":" | sed 's/:$//')

#### Set up standard FSL user environment variables ####

# Debian has a fixed FSLDIR
FSLDIR=/usr/share/fsl/5.0

# Possum is installed in the same directory
POSSUMDIR=$FSLDIR

# add the fsl binary path to the search path
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/fsl/5.0

# The following variable selects the default output image type
# Legal values are:
# NIFTI, NIFTI_PAIR, NIFTI_GZ, NIFTI_PAIR_GZ
# This would typically be overwritten in ${HOME}/.fsl/fsl.sh if the user
# wished to write files with a different format
FSLOUTPUTTYPE=NIFTI_GZ

# Comment out the definition of FSLMULTIFILEQUIT to enable
#  FSL programs to soldier on after detecting multiple image
#  files with the same basename ( e.g. epi.hdr and epi.nii )
FSLMULTIFILEQUIT=TRUE

# The following variables specify paths for programs and can be changed
# or replaced by different programs, by default set sensible Debian-defaults
FSLTCLSH=/usr/bin/tclsh
FSLWISH=/usr/bin/wish
FSLBROWSER=/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser

# The following variables are used for running code in parallel across
#  several machines ( i.e. for FDT )
# for a cluster engine setup see below
FSLLOCKDIR=
FSLMACHINELIST=
FSLREMOTECALL=

# If set, tell FSL to use Sun Gridengine to submit jobs instead of running them
# directly on the machine. If unset, no attempt will be made to utilize
# gridengine, even if it is running. By default SGE is not utilized.
#FSLPARALLEL=1

# Mail setup for gridengine jobs. See man qsub (-m option) for all possible
# settings. By default no email is sent.
FSLCLUSTER_MAILOPTS="n"

# default queue for job submissions
#FSLCLUSTER_DEFAULT_QUEUE="all.q"

###################################################
####    DO NOT ADD ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE    ####
###################################################

export FSLDIR POSSUMDIR PATH FSLMULTIFILEQUIT FSLOUTPUTTYPE FSLTCLSH \
       FSLWISH FSLBROWSER FSLLOCKDIR FSLMACHINELIST FSLREMOTECALL


# Configure the linker search path for Debian FSLs internal shared libraries
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/fsl/5.0${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# load user configuration
if [ -f "${HOME}/.fslconf/fsl.sh" ] ; then
"${HOME}/.fslconf/fsl.sh" ;
fi
```

How can I run this script?

Comment: In your [previous question](http://askubuntu.com/q/523606/147044), you said that you want to source that file in the `.profile` file. In fact there is a comment in that file which say that you should source the file in `.bashrc` file. And now you say that you source the sh script editing `csh.cshrc`? Why? You can't source a bash file in tcsh/csh. A variable [is declared different](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcsh-csh-c_shell-set-variable-command/) in tcsh/csh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the file you are sourcing is a mix of bashisms/shisms that are not supported by tcsh, starting by how you declare variables:

```sh
PATH=$( echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep  -v "/usr/lib/fsl/" | tr -s "\n" ":" | sed  's/:$//')
```

This doesn't work in tcsh. You must modify it to:

```sh
set PATH = `echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | grep  -v "/usr/lib/fsl/" | tr -s "\n" ":" | sed  's/:$//'`
```

In this case, there are two changes. You must explicitly say you are going to set a variable using `set` and tcsh doesn't support the `$(...)` subshells, you need to use backticks `` `...` ``.

Also, the if..else is wrong, it should be:

```sh
if (-f "${HOME}/.fslconf/fsl.sh") then
  "${HOME}/.fslconf/fsl.sh" ;
endif
```

That should do it. The full reference can be found in [oocities](http://www.oocities.org/gurucoder/Tools/sys/tcsh_syntax.txt).

Oh, forgot to add, since `set` is explicit, you don't need any of the `export VAR`. Just remove them.