# Transfer locale settings from my computer to a ssh

Tags: ssh, locale

I wanted to import `locale` from my computer to a ssh. Therefore I did :

```
locale > import
```

Added export on each lines (Do you know any scripting to do it automatically ?)

Copied it from my computer to the ssh :

```
scp import blablabla@hehehe:~/AFolder
```

runned it with `./import` but nothing changed at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and add the content of the `import` file (taken from the remote host)

Answer (score 3):

Your `import` file presumably looks something like this:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=
```

first of all, that's not an executable, so you can't just run it. In any case, what you want to do is *source* it, not execute it (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/601131/85695) for details ont he various ways of executing/sourcing a file). So you want to do `. import` and not `./import`.

As for scripting it, here's a simple way:

```
locale | sed 's/^/export /' > import
scp import blablabla@hehehe:~/AFolder
ssh blablabla@hehehe
. import
```