# execute script when closing terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to execute a specific sh script when closing a terminal.

I edited the `.bash-logout` file, added this line of code inside if statement

```
[ -x /home/user/Documents/logout_msg.sh ] && /home/user/Documents/logout_msg
```

I made `logout_msg.sh` executable, and also outside of if statement I added basic echo message with sleep command after, but this is not showing when closing the terminal.

What might be the problem?

Comment: When should it be executed? Before the terminal closes or after? If after, are you expecting to be able to see anything? And how would you close the terminal? Using the mouse or with `exit` or `Ctrl+D`?

Comment: It should be executed after closing terminal with mouse or exit command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~/.bash_logout` file is only [sourced](https://askubuntu.com/a/601131/85695) when you exit a login shell (from `man bash`):

> When an interactive login shell exits, or a non-interactive login shell executes
> the exit builtin command,  bash  reads  and  executes  commands  from  the  file
> ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

When you open a terminal, you are running an interactive non-login shell, so `~/.bash_logout` is not relevant. For more on the different types of shell, see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/85695).

In order to have something executed each time you close the terminal, you could use `trap` to set a command to run every time an interactive bash session exits. To do this, add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
trap /home/user/Documents/logout_msg.sh EXIT
```

Of course, if that script is printing a message to the terminal, you need to make sure your `logout_msg.sh` includes a `sleep` command so the user will have time to read the message. Something like:

```
echo "Whatever message you want"
sleep 10 ## wait for 10 seconds
```

Comment: The actual goal is to execute sh script which will clear history then show time spend in terminal after delay 5 secs and it will close

Comment: @ViktorSokolov then this should work. See update. Just add a `sleep` call inside the `logout_msg.sh` script.

Comment: Thank You!  What about if I want to close it with a mouse?

Comment: i used SIGHUP command alongside with EXIT but this didn't work

Comment: @ViktorSokolov I don't think it will be possible with a mouse. That kills the terminal GUI process, which is the parent process of the bash shell. That has nothing to do with bash itself. You would somehow have to capture the mouse click on the X and have it do something different. I really doubt it will be possible (I mean, it will be possible, but very very complicated).

Comment: Just noting that capturing the 'X' works without a problem using a `trap` on `SIGHUP` for git-bash under Windows 10. I am not deeply into that stuff, just mentioning that I can use that to automatically stop the `ssh-agent` when closing a git-bash window by mouse click.