# Is there a default way to run commands on user's logout?

Tags: bash, login, users, .profile

I want to log the logins/logouts of my users.

For the logins I only need to modify `/etc/profile` and add my command or edit any `.profile` for an specific user.

But for the logouts I don't know if there is a default/centralized way to do it like `/etc/profile` for logins.

I see some example for CLI sessions, but I want to register GUI/CLI sessions.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you can rely on /etc/profile for non-shell sessions in general - even for logins. To do this properly, you'll probably need to use PAM. See for example [Hook into linux authentication to run script or program when certain conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284624/hook-into-linux-authentication-to-run-script-or-program-when-certain-conditions) or another project that appears to be more active [pam-hooks](https://upsilon.cc/~zack/hacking/software/pam-hooks/)

Comment: thanks for the comment, i've been using /etc/profile without problems and works smoothly. Nevertheless i'll check it out your recommendation

Comment: I'm not saying `/etc/profile` can't work - it's just that it relies on the user's X (or Wayland etc.) session being started as a child of a Bourne-type login shell - which is not a given. See for example [X session wrapper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#X_session_wrapper).

Comment: Actions upon logout won't run in the event of a crash or system reset or power loss. So you must also create a check at login to discover whether the logout job ran.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute script when closing terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021971/execute-script-when-closing-terminal)

Answer (score 2):

Found this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208277/how-can-i-set-a-bash-logout-for-all-users

From the manual (man bash):

```
When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.
```

Comment: that is for CLI not for GUI, isn't it?

Comment: I know it works for CLI. Not sure about GUI however. If you are wanting specifically for GUI I must have misunderstood the question. I'm not sure of in that case