# What are the differences between commands "t.sh" ". t.sh" "/t.sh" "./t.sh"?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am new in shells, so I stuck with this kind of question. What is the simplest way to differentiate those commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between executing shell scripts using "source file.sh", "./file.sh", "sh file.sh", ". ./file.sh"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601055/what-are-the-differences-between-executing-shell-scripts-using-source-file-sh)

Answer (score 12):

- for `t.sh` the shell will search the `PATH` in order for a file named `t.sh` and execute it if it finds it
- for `. t.sh` the shell will search the `PATH` in order for a file named `t.sh` but *source* it if it finds it.

  In the case of the bash shell, the search behavior for sourced commands has additional considerations, as noted in `man bash`:

> ```
>   When  bash  is  not  in  posix  mode,  the  current directory is
>   searched if no file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath  option
>   to  the  shopt  builtin  command  is turned off, the PATH is not
>   searched.
> ```

- for `/t.sh` the shell will look for file `t.sh` in the filesystem root directory `/` and attempt to execute it
- for `./t.sh` the shell will look for file `t.sh` in the shell's current working directory `.` and attempt to execute it

See also

- [What are the differences between executing shell scripts using “source file.sh”, “./file.sh”, “sh file.sh”, “. ./file.sh”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601055/what-are-the-differences-between-executing-shell-scripts-using-source-file-sh)
- [What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that bash's built-in `.` behaves differently in that it looks for files in the working directory if no files were found in `PATH`.

Comment: it might be worth also noting that for security reasons the current directory is frequently not in PATH, so one might have to do ./t.sh instead of t.sh frequently.