# Difference between "./" and ". " for running a script/application?

Tags: bash, scripts

I always ran scripts using `./`

For example `./script.sh`

I recently learned that you can also type `. script.sh`

Is there any difference?

The second is much easier for me since my keyboard doesn't have a key for / but I need to press `SHIFT -`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `./script.sh` the script is run in a subshell. So any operation/change that the script is meant to do is taken place at the subshell, hence the parent shell i.e. from the shell the script was called from remains unaffected of the changes.

On the other hand, when you do `. script.sh` (`.` is the same as shell builtin `source`), the script is source meaning all the commands are executed in this instance of shell (from which it is called). Hence any changes in attributes such as variables, functions declaration affects the shell.

Normally `source` is used for user configuration files e.g. `~/.bashrc` after making any modification to it e.g. adding a new path to `PATH`, so that the change is applied from the current shell session.

Perhaps an example will make you more clear :

```
$ cat script.sh  ##Our test script, containing just a variable (spam) declaration 
#!/bin/bash
spam=foobar

$ ./script.sh  ## Execute using ./script.sh

$ echo "$spam"  ## Prints nothing


$ . script.sh  ## Lets source it

$ echo "$spam"  ## Now we get it
foobar
```

Comment: `.` is not a shorthand for shell builtin `source`, that is the other way around : `source`, which came later, is a longhand for the builtin `.`

Comment: You might also add that if a sourced script exits, then the 'outer' shell (the one sourcing it) exits as well. So if `script.sh` in your example contained the statement `exit`, then _invoking_ it with `./script.sh` will (seem to) do nothing, whereas _sourcing_ it from a terminal with `. script.sh` will have the surprising effect of making the terminal vanish. BTW, the exact same question [has been asked and answered before](http://askubuntu.com/q/107969/134479).

Answer (score 1):

Both execute the script that is located in the same directory that you are in, i.e. your current working directory.

Doing `. script` is referred to as *sourcing the script* in `bash`

From http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html

> When a file is sourced (by typing either source filename or . filename
>   at the command line), the lines of code in the file are executed as if
>   they were printed at the command line. This is particularly useful
>   with complex prompts, to allow them to be stored in files and called
>   up by sourcing the file they are in.
>
> In examples, you will find that I often include #!/bin/bash at the
>   beginning of files including functions. This is not necessary if you
>   are sourcing a file, just as it isn't necessary to chmod +x a file
>   that is going to be sourced. I do this because it makes Vim (my editor
>   of choice, no flames please - you use what you like) think I'm editing
>   a shell script and turn on colour syntax highlighting.

There's a point to notice: the script is executed as if it was *typed on the command line*, meaning it expects `bash` syntax. Thus if you currently are working in `bash` and you want to execute a script that is written in `tcsh` style, bash will complain. By contrast  if you do `. bashstylescript.sh` that will work.

Here's a demo of that. `cwhile.sh` is in `tcsh` style and `whileloop.sh` is in `bash` style.

```
 serg@ubuntu [/home/xieerqi]
================================
$ . cwhile.sh
bash: cwhile.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
 serg@ubuntu [/home/xieerqi]
================================
$ . whileloop.sh 
    28206 
    33672 
    18406 
    65344 
    12022 
    10751 
    29707 
    44303 
    15081 
    59236
```

What about `./script` ? In that case , the shell will read `#!` line, and run the appropriate shell to execute your script.

```
 serg@ubuntu [/home/xieerqi]
================================
$ ./cwhile.sh 
Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
```

As you can see, shell reads my `#!/bin/tcsh` line and lets `tcsh` execute the script.

**Side-note** : Doing `. script.sh` in other shells might not work, since it seems to be bash only thing. `mksh` for instance does not do that, but rather uses `source script.sh` way

Comment: That's the other way around, `. script.sh` is standard so should be supported by most shells (both bourne style and csh style) while `source` is originally a bashism.

Comment: So I guess `mksh` is just the odd one and doesn't support `. Script.sh` ?

Comment: mksh does actually support `. script.sh`

Comment: @jlliagre  then why it doesn't work for me ?

Comment: I have no explanation but I guess some mistake in your test case. AFAIK, mksh has always supported the `.` builtin. Before it, pdksh already supported it too. Not doing it would have been a very serious bug. In any case, you haven't provided any evidence it doesn't work for you but if you can post a repeatable test case, that might deserve its own question.