# Can no longer set terminal title in Ubuntu 16 (gnome-terminal)

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 14.10 LTS, I was able to set a terminal tab's title simply by right-clicking and choosing *Set Title*. This was using the default terminal application, `gnome-terminal`.

In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I can no longer set the title, and the terminal application is still `gnome-terminal`. The option *Set Title* is no longer in the menu.

Was this feature removed sometime between 14.10 and 16.04? **How can I set a terminal tab's title in Ubuntu 16.04?**

Comment: How I couldn't find the original in my searching, I don't know. Thanks to those who found it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The option to set the terminal title has been deprecated in 16.04 LTS, however there is still a way to set the title. Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add the following lines:

```bsh
# function to set terminal title
function set-title(){
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

After that close and reopen the terminal or source your `.bashrc` (command: `source ~/.bashrc`) and you can set the title by simply typing:

```
set-title "<title>"
```

The [solution I found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186167/166226) and using it myself since I run on 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Probably yes, just test it, as it only screws the actual open terminal in the worst case you should be safe for testing

Comment: Somehow it just has no effect when run from inside my other script .. but only when run as a command in the shell directly .. will check some more (LTS 18.04)

Comment: Probably because your script is running in a subshell.

Comment: Bingo. that solved it. need to source the script [rather than execute it normally as a sub-shell](https://askubuntu.com/a/661580/208696). many thanks!!

Comment: It messes up with long statements