# desktop shortcut to terminal-app of another user possible?

Tags: command-line, sudo, users, .desktop

I'm new to ubuntu and logged in as user abc (shows Desktop)

I need to call the following app when I'm logged in as user abc: /home/xyz/zzzapp/zzz -param1 -param2

user abc and xyz are members of sudo.

I'd like to have a .desktop shortcut on abc that logs in as user xyz opens a terminal and calls the app zzz -param1 -param2

If terminal asks me for password it's ok for me

how can I do this?

Comment: which desktop do you have on your Ubuntu? GNOME, MATE, ... ?

Comment: which desktop - I installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS - the default one

Answer (score 1):

The ~/.local/share/applications/zzz.desktop file will look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Run zzz as xyz
Exec=bash -c 'su -c "/home/xyz/zzzapp/zzz -param1 -param2" xyz; read -p "Hit Enter to close terminal:"'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

---

Why do you need a desktop icon? I would recommend this:

1. add this function to your ~/.bashrc

   ```
   zzz() { su -c '~/zzzapp/zzz -param1 "$(bash get_ggggg.sh)"' -l xyz; }
   ```
2. when you want to run it, open a gnome-terminal and enter the command `zzz`

Comment: thank you, works great!

However I just found out that param 2 is actually something like this:

zzz -param1 `bash get_ggggg.sh` --> bash: get_gggg.sh: no such file or directory

Further is it possible to just start a command shell in the home directory?
e.g.: ckick on icon, login - command shell for xyz starts where I can input custom commands

Comment: when I put the bash get_ggg.sh into double single quotes instead of one single quote: error diappears on calling however command error: too many arguments as reply from zzz app

Comment: "double single quotes" are useless. See update in my answer

Comment: function: thanks for the great idea! However when I start my app zzz reports: Error:
              (Invalid_argument "Utils.parse_addr_port: IPv6 addresses must
            be bracketed") ----> note: start it normally in command shell works. Any suggestions?

Comment: No. Insufficient data.

Comment: Is it possible to just start a command shell with the other user in the home directory? e.g.: abc's desktop: ckick on icon, login - command shell for xyz starts where I can input custom commands

Comment: `su -l xyz` does that

Comment: Thank you very much! Side note -l for login not minus one worked: 'Exec=bash -c 'su -l  xyz' '

Comment: Is there any chance to show a different /  additional text on the terminal windows? Curently only "Terminal" is shown. Better to distinguish would be "Terminal myXYZtext"

Comment: terminal title: found this, but it did not work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777833/can-no-longer-set-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-gnome-terminal/777836  - I can set a title in an open cmd-shell however  it doesn't work like this: ' Exec=bash -c 'su -c "/home/xyz/zzzapp/zzz -param1 -param2" xyz; set-title "hello"; read -p "Hit Enter to close terminal:"'  ' - any suggestions?

Comment: The perfect solution would be if the [Desktop Entry]    Name=myTitle       could be displayed in the title. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: terminal-title: resolved here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049970/how-to-pass-a-teminal-title-to-a-terminal-opend-via-desktop-shortcut-desktop