# How to pass a terminal-title to a terminal opened via desktop shortcut (.desktop)?

Tags: command-line, .desktop

Is there a way to set a title to a terminal that is opend via desktop shortcut?

The perfect solution would be if the [Desktop Entry] Name=myTitle could be displayed in the title. Does anyone know if this is possible?

See also (approach here didn't work): [desktop shortcut to terminal-app of another user possible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049550/desktop-shortcut-to-terminal-app-of-another-user-possible)

based on this: [Can no longer set terminal title in Ubuntu 16 (gnome-terminal)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777833/can-no-longer-set-terminal-title-in-ubuntu-16-gnome-terminal/777836)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of based on my [previous answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/860484/295286), would be to spawn terminal with command that sets title  + spawns interactive shell of your choice. Specifically, I would make the `Exec=` part of the `.desktop` file as so:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;TEST1\007\";bash'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm new to Ubuntu, how can I accomplish this with my existing entry which starts an app zzz from another user xyz:  '   Exec=bash -c 'su -c "/home/xyz/zzz -param1 " xyz;  read -p "Hit Enter to close terminal:"'  '

Comment: @ssssstut So you probably should just add the `printf` part (which is what does setting the title of the terminal) before `su`. Specifically, with your example, I'd do  `Exec=bash -c 'printf \"\033]0;TEST1\007\"; su -c "/home/xyz/zzz -param1 " xyz; read -p "Hit Enter to close terminal:"' '`

Comment: doesn't work, says: "033]0bash: TEST1007": command not found  (wants to exec ;TEST1 as cmd)

Comment: Alright. I'll try to fix it later.  Right now using phone, so don't have terminal

Comment: resolved it: this did the trick: " Exec=bash -c 'printf "\033]0;TEST1\007"; su -c ..." --> shows the title TEST1

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -t myTitle -e myCommand ...
```

in your desktop file. See also the gnome-terminal help output:

```
$ gnome-terminal --help-terminal-options
Usage:
  gnome-terminal [OPTION…] [-- COMMAND …]

Terminal options; if used before the first --window or --tab argument, sets the default for all terminals:
  -e, --command                   Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal
  --profile=PROFILE-NAME          Use the given profile instead of the default profile
  -t, --title=TITLE               Set the initial terminal title
  --working-directory=DIRNAME     Set the working directory
  --wait                          Wait until the child exits
  --fd=FD                         Forward file descriptor
  --zoom=ZOOM                     Set the terminal’s zoom factor (1.0 = normal size)
```