# . configure issue

Tags: configure

I tried to run the below command in order to procede to install a program:

```
$ . configure
```

but after few second the Ubuntu terminal close, without any message.
What happened?

Thanks for your time about my issue

Comment: You probably should follow description and run `./configure` instead.

Comment: Oh by doing that you're making the **configure** script the [source](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) script in your terminal.If you want to execute the configure script in the current directory normally , you should refer to the current directory **.** followed by a **/** . Just a single dot is equal to the **source** command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "source x", ". x" and "./x" in Bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107969/what-is-the-difference-between-source-x-x-and-x-in-bash). The example in that script is quite fitting your question ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all comments, but now I got another problem after run ./configure

Comment: ./configure gnu

  Testing C++ compiler:
Error: Test compile failed: g++  -Wall  -O3     -o testp testp.cpp
Error: Check the output below for error messages:
./configure: line 381: g++: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing that you're running the **configure** script in the current shell similar to `exec bash -e ./configure` or simply `source ./configure` .

Dot followed by a space is equivalent to the [source command](https://superuser.com/a/618442/1087371) , but if you want to execute the **configure** script in the current directory , you have to add a slash between the **dot** and **configure** :

```
./configure
```

The bash first spawns a new shell then executes it in the child shell.But if you use the source command or `. configure` , you're actually executing it **instead of** the current bash process.So your terminal will get closed after that since there's no shell to give you a prompt.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, but now I got another problem after run ./configure

Comment: `Testing C++ compiler: Error: Test compile failed: g++ -Wall -O3 -o testp testp.cpp Error: Check the output below for error messages: ./configure: line 381: g++: command not found`

Comment: @Dario You have to install ```g++``` for that(```sudo apt install g++```) .Please check out the required packages in the **README** or **INSTALL.md** of the program you're trying to compile to prevent future errors.

Comment: This time I got this: `dario@dario-VirtualBox:~/cpptraj$ ./configure
No compilers specified; defaulting to gnu
  Testing C++ compiler: OK
  Testing C compiler: OK
  Testing Fortran compiler: OK
  Testing basic C++11 support: OK
  Testing system headers for C++11 support: OK
Warning: Compilation of sanderlib requires AMBERHOME to be set
Warning:   if --with-sanderlib not specified.
  Checking BZLIB:
Error: Test compile failed: g++  -Wall  -O3     -std=gnu++11  -o testp testp.cpp -lbz2    
Error: Check the output below for error messages:
testp.cpp:2:10: fatal error: bzlib.h: `

Comment: @Dario Which project you're trying to build?

Comment: I try to install cpptraj an AmberTools: https://github.com/Amber-MD/cpptraj

Comment: @Dario Please go to [this chat room to resume the discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109585/compiling-the-cpptraj-project).

Comment: Really Thanks for you time, help and kindness.

Comment: @Dario You're welcome. And if that helped you please consider accepting the answer.